# Chess challenge from a newspaper in 1927 (win in 2 moves)

Tags: checkmate, problems

I have been trying to solve this for a long time, but can't find a solution. How can white force a checkmate in 2 moves?

```
1R6/4p3/2pkB3/4n1N1/8/1N2K1B1/8/8 w - - 0 1
```

Comment: If only there was a way to stop `1... c5` ...

Comment: You can solve a mate in two problem by trying every move for White.

Comment: @bof For this reason mate in two problems are actually quite good for practicing your calculation skills. I think Laszlo Polgar used to give such problems to his daughters when they were young.

Comment: On good problems, it is rare that the first move is check.

Comment: I dont think the OP is asking for mate in two moves; hes asking to find, within two moves, a forced mating variation (look at the wording!) Regardless, @Glorfindel has found a mate in two.

Answer (score 10):

Ask yourself: what would Black do if he were to move? After 1... Kc7, 2. Bxe5 is mate. His other option is 1... c5, threatening to escape with 2... Kc6.

The solution:

> 1. Nc5! blocks the c-pawn. Black gets the additional option of 1... Kxc5, but after that, 2. Ne4 is mate.

<sub>(I can post an interactive version, but that doesn't work with spoilers. And it's a good visualization exercise.)</sub>

Comment: There's a second solution . . .

Comment: @pokep maybe; I didn't look any further than this one. If there is one, you can (should) post it as a second answer.

Comment: >! Looks like 1.Nd4 Kc5 (or c5) 2.Ne4 is checkmate

Comment: @RickG after 1. Nd4 c5 2. Ne4 the black king can escape (temporarily) to c7.

Comment: @Glorfindel yup, missed that!

Comment: Actually, this does not guarantee a two-move checkmate. Black could make a dumb move Ng4 or Nc4 after white plays Nc5! to check white's king and delay the checkmate operation.

Comment: @WaisKamal the black knight is pinned.

Comment: Oh yeah didn't give that mucha attention...thanks :)